# How to politely remind a Professor to re-review my application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

I recently applied to a Graduate School and also wrote to a Professor, I really want to work with. She scheduled an interview and it went immensely well and she also said that I would be a fit for her lab. But just before ending the interview, she told me to e-mail her my unique application ID, so she can have a look at my complete application. She said she'll get back to me.

This is was before the Christmas/New Year holidays. I was anticipating a reply but thought of waiting further until the holidays got over. I never received a response. Now that the holidays are over, I want to draft a mail re-reminding her about my application. What would be a polite way of doing this?

So far, I've got this

---

Respected Professor,

Thank you for interviewing me for a position at your lab on MM-DD-YYYY.
According to your instructions, I've mentioned you in my application as a potential supervisor. My application ID is XXXXXXXX. This is a gentle reminder for my application.

Thank you for your time and consideration!

Kind Regards,
XXX YYY

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably wait for some more time. The professor probably took Christmas holidays as a chance to have some time off to spend with her family or doing other things. Don't put pressure on her, let her have another week to carefully look at your application and reply to you with no hurry. In case you don't get a reply by next monday, then it will be appropriate to write an email.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In case she still doesn't respond, any improvements you'd suggest over the mail I've already drafted?

Comment: I think the draft you wrote was pretty good. Maybe I'd remove the "This is a gentle reminder for my application", since the mail itself has the function of a reminder.

Comment: Yes, as @Gixuna comments, first there's no point in noting that your reminder is a reminder, and, second, saying that might be viewed as patronizing or in some other negative way.